# Prevent Bootstrap modal window from opening in new tab / window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I am looking for a way to prevent my modal dialog windows to open for Open in a new tab / window. The modal window has to be opened (on top of current window) only with a direct click and not be displayed when the user right clicks on "Open in new tab / Window". Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you talking about , http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals ?

Comment: yes that's the one I mean

Comment: May be this will help you. [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the element you can use oncontextmenu

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well though not I wanted initially, your response works. Thank you very much. 
Your response disables contextual menu on the link, however I initially wanted it to remain there and if open in new tab is clicked, the current page reopens without modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this will be difficult cross-browser/device wise - open link in new window is same request to browser (no JS way of knowing the difference).

Maybe it could be done with localstorage/cookies and active browser tab detection with some capture right click method (all logically connected in a function) but I think it could be very prone to (cross-browser/device) inconsistencies...

So - personally I would try to write a method:
- checking for right click (don't forget touch devices) - or as shiva proposed (oncontextmenu), saving "state" in localstorage/cookie,
- checking for that state at page init and disabling modal(s) appropriately.

Test on multiple devices...